Identify this Buster Keaton movie
I cannot remember the title of a Buster Keaton movie I saw a few years ago. 
In this movie, the main character, played by Buster Keaton, inherits a house under the condition, he gets married within a day.  To find a bride as fast as possible, he makes an announcement in a newspaper.
In a large portion of the move, Keaton is hunted by a crowd of brides throughout the city.
I went through Keaton's filmography, looking for keywords as marriage or bride and could find references to “The Scarecrow” which is not the right movie.  Going methodically through Keaton's filmography (of over 149 movies) does not appear to be tractable.
What is this movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Did Buster Keaton's filmography turn up anything? You have to give much more than that. Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question and flag it for reopening once you feel confident you did so.

Another advice for future queries: If you know who the star was, try Googling their name with some of the keywords first. When you Google 'Buster Keaton inherits' or 'Buster Keaton must marry within a day', the film you're looking for is literally the first result (at least in my Google).

@NapoleonWilson Thank you for your suggestions, I added as much background as possible.

@Walt This was my first move, but in my Google only references to Keaton's personal life and to other movies like “His Wedding Night”. Also results are very sensitive to the input “Buster Keaton wedding legacy within a day” was my research that did not get any useful result.

@resident_heretic This is actually “Seven Chances,” thank you so much. Do you care about writing a formal answer?

@MichaelGrünewald I only used sentences you wrote in your question, though... Googling them immediately turns up the desired film. But Google results do vary, I guess. Anyway, the film is quite nice IIRC. Glad you found it.

It's "Seven Chances".
You can entertain yourself by keeping track of how many sevens come up in the course of the movie (for starters, the plot kicks off when Keaton's character learns that he stands to inherit seven million dollars).
From Wikipedia:

Jimmy Shannon (Buster Keaton) is the junior partner in the brokerage firm of Meekin and Shannon, which is on the brink of financial ruin. A lawyer (whom they dodged, mistakenly believing he was trying to add to their woes) finally manages to inform Jimmy of the terms of his grandfather's will. He will inherit seven million dollars if he is married by 7:00 p.m. on his 27th birthday, which happens to be that same day.

